# How to run a LISP program

Tags: lisp

Does the LISP program need to be in the same folder as the LISP compiler or can I call it from anywhere?

Comment: This highly depends on how the program is structured (is it an ASDF system? just a bare function? a single .lisp?) and what lisp compiler you're using.

Comment: My favorite way - Seriously - is to run it within emacs.

Comment: It is a basic .lisp file. And I'm not really sure what compiler would be best to use. I have Windows 7 and most of the LISP compilers I have found don't run on Windows.

Comment: What is emacs? I have never heard of it.

Comment: Emacs is a powerful text editor and the favourite IDE of many Lisp programmers (especially combined with SLIME, the Superior Lisp Interaction Mode for Emacs). Emacs uses its own Lisp dialect (Emacs Lisp) as extension language, and most of Emacs itself is actually written in Lisp (there's only a small C core providing the Lisp interpreter and some basic functionality). You can run a Lisp file opened in Emacs directly in it, and don't need to worry about its location on disk.

Comment: Here's the link to Lispbox, a combination of Emacs, SLIME, the Quicklisp library manager, and the Clozure Common Lisp compiler (available for Windows, Mac, and Linux): http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/

Comment: In Lispbox, how do I get my program to run? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Chapter 2 of the book Practical Common Lisp should get you started: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/lather-rinse-repeat-a-tour-of-the-repl.html. Lispbox was originally a version of Lisp in a Box adapted specifically to go with that book, but is now developed independently.

Answer (score 6):

The basic operation is to call `load` with a *pathname*.

```
(load #p"/home/user710086/foo.lisp")
```

Then, you may need to run whatever "main" function is supplied by that file.

The location can also be in the *current directory*, which is, of course, platform dependent.  The *current directory* usually has nothing to do with the directory the Lisp executable resided in, but is the directory of the shell you called it from.  I do not know what the *current directory* is in Windows when you click on something, but I would guess that it is some home-directory-surrogate.

There are several things that may wrap around that basic operation.  Usually, code is organized into an ASDF system, and has defined one or more *packages*.  You would then add the `.asd` file to `asdf:*asdf-registry*` and then load the package with

```
(asdf:load-sys 'foo)
```

This would load all files defined in the `.asd` file in a calculated order, thus providing you with the system's functionality.

Comment: What if I have multiple functions inside of the program? Does it matter which one I run first?

Comment: It does not matter which you _compile_ first (although it may give warnings if an unknown function name is encountered).  You _run_ just the entry point.